# Render Twig with helper through service in phpUnit / Test

Tags: symfony, phpunit, twig

I have a service.

```
manager.summary.order:
    class: Travelyo\CoreBundle\Services\Managers\Order\OrderSummaryManager
    arguments:
        template:       '@templating'
        router: '@router'
```

That render html (using twig) that will be send later by mail or displayed.

When using this service within my Symfony2.1 project, I don't have any problem. In this twig I have different calls like `app.request.locale` & `number_format_currency`.

When calling this service in my Test Controller.

I get that error

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a 
template ("You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope
 ("request").") in "TravelyoCoreBundle:Mail:confirmation_mail.html.twig" at line 63.
```

Here is my Controller.

```
namespace Travelyo\ConfigurationBundle\Tests\Order;

use Travelyo\CoreBundle\Event\Order\OrderEvent;
use Travelyo\CoreBundle\Entity\Order\Order;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Travelyo\CoreBundle\Session\EtSession;
use Travelyo\CoreBundle\Services\Managers\OrderProcessManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class OrderSaveToDbTest extends WebTestCase {
    private $summaryManger;
    public function setUp()
    {
        static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
        static::$kernel->boot();
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request(
                'GET', '/clients/123456',
                array('SERVER_NAME' => 'travelyo'), /* request params */
                array(), /* files */
                array('X-Requested-With' => "XMLHttpRequest",'SERVER_NAME' => 'travelyo'));

        $this->summaryManger = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('manager.summary.order');
    }

    public function testSaveAndSend()
    {
        $this->summaryManger->generateHml();

    }
}
```

Any idea how to not have this error ?

I tried adding scope=request to my service. But this service is used by others services in my application

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the request into your service make your service yml

```
manager.summary.order:
class: Travelyo\CoreBundle\Services\Managers\Order\OrderSummaryManager
arguments:
    template:       '@templating'
    router: '@router'
    - "@service_container"
```

Then in your service file you need to add a constructor:

```
namespace Travelyo\ConfigurationBundle\Tests\Order;

class OrderSaveToDbTest extends WebTestCase {

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /* the rest of your controller/service */
}
```

Then to use the container to get the request is really easy:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
```

I may have some of this not exactly correct, but its on the general idea. Check out this link for more reading on working with scopes: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html